# Flutter problem with saving the value from document from database to a initState value

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with fetching value from database document to a variable called in initState method. When I am doing that there is a problem with null value and I think that get() method from Firebase is taking the value too late(it happens when i reload the scene).

```
  bool _dark;
  bool options;
  MainModel model;
  final MyUser myUser;
  final UserSettings userSettings;

  _SettingsOnePageState(this.userSettings, this.myUser);

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _dark = false;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("settings")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      print(value.data()['darkMode']);
      _dark = value.data()['darkMode'];
    });
    options = false;
  }

  Brightness _getBrightness() {
    return _dark ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light;
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
        // return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
        isMaterialAppTheme: true,
        data: ThemeData(
          brightness: _getBrightness(),
        ),
        // value: SettingsUser().settings,
        child: StreamBuilder<UserSettings>(
            //setting the stream for settings from database
            stream: DatabaseUser(userId: user.uid).userData,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                //data for user from database
                UserSettings userSettings = snapshot.data;
                // _dark = userSettings.darkMode;
                // print("dark mode " + userSettings.darkMode.toString());
                return Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Scaffold(
                        backgroundColor: _dark ? null : Colors.grey.shade200,
                        appBar: AppBar(
                          //elevation: 10,
                          brightness: _getBrightness(),
                          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                              color: _dark ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          title: Text(
                            'Change theme',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: _dark ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.auto_awesome),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  _dark = !_dark;
                                });
                              },
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        body: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                              //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        child: Text(
                                          userSettings.nick,
                                          textScaleFactor: 4,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: _dark
                                                ? Colors.white
                                                : Colors.purple[500],
                                            //fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          ),
                                        )),
                                    const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Container(
                                        // width: 200,
                                        // height: 200,
                                        child: CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 100.0,
                                          backgroundImage:
                                              //NetworkImage(user.photoURL),
                                              NetworkImage(
                                                  userSettings.pictureUrl),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                //const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                                if (options == true) ...[
                                  //SettingsEdit(),
                                  //NickChange(),
                                  ImageInput(),
                                ],
                                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                                Card(
                                  elevation: 4.0,
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                      32.0, 8.0, 32.0, 16.0),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading: Icon(
                                          Icons.account_box,
                                          color: Colors.purple,
                                        ),
                                        title: Text("Change Nickname"),
                                        trailing:
                                            Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          //open change nick
                                          //changeNick();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      _buildDivider(),
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading: Icon(
                                          Icons.add_a_photo,
                                          color: Colors.purple,
                                        ),
                                        title: Text("Change Photo"),
                                        trailing:
                                            Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          //open change photo
                                          //changePhoto();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      _buildDivider(),
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading: Icon(
                                          Icons.lock_rounded,
                                          color: Colors.purple,
                                        ),
                                        title: Text("Change Password"),
                                        trailing:
                                            Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          //open change password
                                          //changePassword();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      _buildDivider(),
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading: Icon(
                                          Icons.location_on,
                                          color: Colors.purple,
                                        ),
                                        title: Text("Change Your Location"),
                                        trailing:
                                            Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          //open change location
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                              ]))
                        ])));
              }
              return Scaffold();
            }));
  }
```

[debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNSTB.png)
[settings where I use theme now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5juX3.png)

Do you know how to avoid this null in initState? I am trying to change theme of the app and I am taking that from Firebase document whick I created when the user registered. Than I will be changing it in user settings and also want to use it(this theme) in whole app.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InitState` is not async (meaning execution doesn't wait for your firebase call to complete). This means that your view will be rendered before you assign `_dark` a value.

If you want to wait until that call is complete, use something called [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).